# How to put url constant in php while loop echo for outputting as json

Tags: php, constants

I have a file - constants.php with constants defined like so -

```
if (!defined('url')) define("url",     "example.com", true);
```

I want to include this url in another php file which is connecting to mysql and using while loop to output json

```
echo '  "url": ' . '"' ."http://.url./s.php?o=$o" . '"' ;
```

It should output in the json file as

```
"url": "http://example.com/s.php?o=a+b"
```

but it is showing in the json output as

```
"url": "http://.url./s.php?o=a+b"
```

Please tell what I am doing wrong

Comment: Are you manually creating JSON with strings? I'd advise against that and instead build an array of data and use json_encode. http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: @Aknosis , After the data is fetched from the mysql, it is further modified by different functions for different parameters. So, I am manually creating JSON in the php while loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are just missing some double quotes around url: `".url."`

```
echo '  "url": ' . '"' ."http://".url."/s.php?o=$o" . '"' . '' . "";
```

You have to use the same quotes to enclose your strings. I will explain by breaking apart the entire statement into individual parts and the string as it is being built:

```
echo 
'  "url": '     "url":
'"'             "url": "
"http://"       "url": "http://
url             "url": "http://{url constant value}
"/s.php?o=$o"   "url": "http://{url constant value}/s.php?o={$o value}
'"'             "url": "http://{url constant value}/s.php?o={$o value}"
''              "url": "http://{url constant value}/s.php?o={$o value}"
"";             "url": "http://{url constant value}/s.php?o={$o value}"
```

The last two parts of the string concatenation you don't need as you are just adding empty spaces.

Simpler: `echo '  "url": ' . '"' ."http://".url."/s.php?o=$o" . '"';`

Comment: Thanks for responding. Already tried that. Then, it is outputting as `"url": "http://'.url.'/s.php?o=a+b"`

Comment: Actually those should be double quotes, I updated my post.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. Can you please explain the logic of putting in between double quotes and not in single quotes

Comment: @user20152015 Updated my answer. You have to use double quotes because that is the type of quote that you were using to wrap the http://  and /s.php parts of the string

Comment: @Anosis, Can you give any documentation link for such syntax rules. I always run into problems here

Comment: From your link, found the real reason why double quotes are needed - `The most important feature of double-quoted strings is the fact that variable names will be expanded. See string parsing for details`

Comment: @user20152015 Correct. This doesn't work for constants so in your case it is needed for proper concatenation

Answer (score 1):

This line with `echo` is really complex. It's hard to understand what is going on, when reading this line. You can avoid this problem using `sprintf` method instead of strings concatenation.

```
<?php

if (!defined('url')) define("url", "example.com", true);

$o = 1;

echo sprintf('"url": "http://%s/s.php?o=%s"', url, $o);
```

Anyway, the best variant is to use `json_encode`.

```
<?php

if (!defined('url')) define("url", "example.com", true);

$o = 1;

$data = [
    'url' => sprintf('http://%s/s.php?o=%s', url, $o),
];
// if you want to have unescaped slashes,
// you need to provide JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES flag.
echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Comment: +1 for giving alternate. Edited and simplified the echo line `echo '  "url": ' . '"' ."http://.url./s.php?o=$o" . '"' ;`

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
echo '  "url": ' . '"' ."http://". url ."/s.php?o=$o" . '"' . '' . "";
```